# conj not updating vector inside of loop

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to teach myself clojure. This is just supposed to be a simple function that takes a value and adds each of its preceding values together and returns the sum of those values.

The problem is that while in the `loop` function, `numbers` isn't modified with `conj` like I would expect it to be - `numbers` just stays an empty vector. Why is that?

```
(defn sum                        
  [number]                       
  (do (def numbers (vector))     
    (loop [iteration number]     
      (if (> iteration 0)        
        (conj numbers iteration) 
        (recur (dec iteration))))
    (map + numbers)))
```

Comment: `conj` doesn't modify its argument, it *returns a new vector* with the element added.

Comment: Ah I see, then I need to re-think how I'm doing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function does not work fro three main reasons :

- you assumed that conj will update the value of variable `numbers` (but in fact it returns a copy of it bound to another name)
- you used `loop/recur` pattern like in classical imperative style (it does not work the same)
- Bad use of `map`

Thumbnail gave the idiomatic answer but here are correct use of your pattern :

```
(defn sum
  [number]
  (loop [iteration number
         numbers []]
    (if (<= iteration 0)
          (reduce + numbers)
          (recur (dec iteration) (conj numbers iteration)))))
```

The loop/recur pattern executes its body with updated values passed by `recur`.
Recur updates values listed after the `loop`. Here, while iteration is strictly positive, `recur` is executed. However, when iteration reaches 0, `(reduce + numbers)` (actual sum) is executed on the result of multiple recursions and so the recursion ends.

Comment: This helped explain loop/recur clearly to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

A few hints (not an answer):

- Don't use `do`.
- Use `let`, not `def`, inside a function.
- Use the result *returned* by `conj`, or it does nothing.
- Pass the result back through the `recur`.

Besides, your `sum` function ignores its `number` argument.

I think you're getting confused between `number` (the number of things you want to add) and `numbers` (the things themselves). Remember,

- vectors (and other data structures) know how long they are; and
- they are often, as in what follows, quickly and concisely dealt with as
  sequences, using `first` and `rest` instead of indexing.

---

The code pattern you are searching for is so common that it's been captured in a standard *higher order function* called `reduce`. You can get the effect you want by ...

```
(defn sum [coll] (reduce + coll))
```

or

```
(def sum (partial reduce +))
```

For example,

```
(sum (range 10))
;45
```

---

**Somewhat off-topic:**

If I were you, and I once was, I'd go through some of the fine clojure tutorials available on the web, *with a REPL to hand*. You could start looking [here](http://www.learn-clojure.com/clojure_tutorials.html) or [here](https://www.clojure.org/community/resources). Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm going to check them out!